# Как автоматически задать область страницы?

Tags: javascript, php

Как автоматически задать область просмотра страницы?

То есть, если сделать через якорь, то будет типа

`index.html#link`,

а в самом тексте можно вставить

`<a id="link"></a>`.

И при переходе на

`index.html#link`

посетителя автоматом кидало на ту часть текста, где расположен

`<a id="link"></a>`.

Возможно ли это организовать через `js, php`?

Ссылка на запись вида сайт/категория/запись/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. через JS - да, window.location.href= ....
2. через пхп нельзя, [читаем внимательно](http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke)

Comment: <script>
window.location.href = "#link"; 
</script>
Не помогло.

Comment: document.location.href...